# Convert a sorted doubly linked list to a balanced BST in-place in constant space

Tags: sorting, recursion, linked-list, binary-search-tree

Is there any way to convert a sorted doubly linked list to a balanced BST in-place **in constant space**?

The best ways I found ([1], [2], [3]) leverage recursion, but they need more than constant space for the recursion stack. I guess there might be some way to precompute the indexes without the recursion. However, I cannot find a good way to do so.

This question is part of the solution for an interview question which requires to merge 2 BST into a balanced search tree with constant space [4].

[1] [Converting a sorted doubly linked list to a BST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874517/converting-a-sorted-doubly-linked-list-to-a-bst) 
[2] http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/in-place-conversion-of-sorted-dll-to-balanced-bst/ 
[3] http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-linked-list-to-balanced-bst/ 
[4] http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5261732222074880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is something like vine_to_tree(), normally used as part of rebalancing a binary search tree. The normal process start off with tree_to_vine(), which creates a tree with only right nodes, essentially a sorted doubly linked list, which is where you're starting from. Then vine_to_tree() is used to create a balanced binary tree. Usually several functions are involved, but it's a non recursive algorithm.

Do a web search and you should find a few examples of vine_to_tree(), like this one:

http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~qstout/pap/CACM86.pdf

What you want in this case is vine_to_tree() using perfect_leaves(). Example code:

```
struct node {
    size_t value;
    node *p_left;
    node *p_right;
};
// defines to use for double link list nodes
#define p_prev p_left
#define p_next p_right

size_t floor_power_of_two(size_t size)
{
size_t n = 1;
    while(n <= size)
        n = n + n;
    return n/2;
}

size_t ceil_power_of_two(size_t size)
{
size_t n = 1;
    while(n < size)
        n = n + n;
    return n;
}

// split vine nodes, placing all even (0, 2, 4, ...) leaves on left branches
// p_root->p_right->p_left = 0, p_root->p_right->p_right->p_left = 2
node * perfect_leaves(node * p_root, size_t leaf_count, size_t size)
{
node *p_scanner;
node *p_leaf;
size_t i;
size_t hole_count;
size_t next_hole;
size_t hole_index;
size_t leaf_positions;

    if(leaf_count == 0)
        return p_root;
    leaf_positions = ceil_power_of_two(size+1)/2;
    hole_count = leaf_positions - leaf_count;
    hole_index = 1;
    next_hole = leaf_positions / hole_count;
    p_scanner = p_root;
    for(i = 1; i < leaf_positions; i += 1){
        if(i == next_hole){
            p_scanner = p_scanner->p_right;
            hole_index = hole_index + 1;
            next_hole = (hole_index * leaf_positions) / hole_count;
        } else {
            p_leaf = p_scanner->p_right;
            p_scanner->p_right = p_leaf->p_right;
            p_scanner = p_scanner->p_right;
            p_scanner->p_left = p_leaf;
            p_leaf->p_right = NULL;
        }
    }
    return p_root;
}

//  left rotate sub-tree
node * compression(node * p_root, size_t count)
{
node *p_scanner;
node *p_child;
size_t i;
    p_scanner = p_root;
    for(i = 1; i <= count; i += 1){
        p_child = p_scanner->p_right;
        p_scanner->p_right = p_child->p_right;
        p_scanner = p_scanner->p_right;
        p_child->p_right = p_scanner->p_left;
        p_scanner->p_left = p_child;
    }
    return p_root;
}

//  convert vine to perfect balanced tree
node * vine_to_tree(node *p_root, size_t size)
{
size_t leaf_count; // # of leaves if not full tree
    leaf_count = size + 1 - floor_power_of_two(size+1);
    perfect_leaves(p_root, leaf_count, size);
    size = size - leaf_count;
    while(size > 1){
        compression(p_root, size / 2);
        size = size / 2;
    }
    return p_root;
}
```